# only getting partial async behavior asp.NET (thread or request limit issue maybe?)

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, asynchronous, request

I won't get into specifics unless I need to, but I have an app which loads 8 widgets in what should be an async manner. Instead, though, only 3 or so of them are loading asynchronously, and then the others end up getting queued and wait for the first ones to finish. Each of the widget actions has at least one web service call, so that is a factor too. I assume its just a thread or request limitation from a browser, or IIS, or whatever. The problem, though, is that IIS isn't freeing up the threads from the first few widgets to be used for the other ones. Even after the first few are totally done loading, there seems to be only one usable thread.

I am testing on a windows 7 machine with iis7.

If any more info is needed let me know..

Comment: Are the web service calls coming from javascript or server side? The browser will only load a certain number of items from a single domain in parallel, so there is a limitation there.

Comment: Its coming from the server, and yeah I was aware of that limit. But the main problem is that either the threads or the connection sockets aren't freeing up. If i could get three of them to load async, then 3 more async, then 2 more async, then I'd be happy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a session lock issue. Readonly session state fixed this.